# Overlay one activity partially on another

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout

I am creating android apps by self learning. I have tried searching for this everywhere but have not found it.

My exact question is how do I create the layout shown below. I want the Activity2 to slide up and down with up and down swipes respectively.

[image: Swipe up shows Activity 2 and swipe down shows Activity1 with partial Activity 2]

Comment: You should working on fragments:https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: I thought that it maybe would require fragments. Thank you for confirming it.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BottomSheet](https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066) to perform this.

Comment: Could you tell me how does one go about finding unfamiliar functions that serve the purpose? For example BottomSheet in this case. How do you conduct research? On the android studio reference documents or another website?

Comment: @Newbie please refer the link. Its well explained.

Comment: @Santosh No no I understood that.Thank you for that. I was trying to ask how do you start a search process, for example like this question. This is my first time trying to  learn something in-depth by myself.